# SpriteKit Collision jumping

Tags: collision-detection, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I got 2 objects, a Human and a Block. If the Human is on the Block, he is able to jump,
if he is in the air, he isn't. How can I code that, cause the CGRectIntersectsRect doesn't work in SpriteKit for me.

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

```
Human.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

[Human.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 40)];
```

}

I got the Block and the Human already in Categorys, for Collision detection :

```
else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & HumanCategory) != 0 &&
         (secondBody.categoryBitMask & BlockCategory) != 0)
{

}
```

Should I use that somehow for the code? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent jumping when not touching the ground use [bodyAtPoint:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsWorld/bodyAtPoint%3a) to detect whether or not there is any physics body directly underneath your node.

If it is possible that there will be multiple physics bodies under your character that may not be relevant you can use [enumerateBodiesAtPoint:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsWorld/enumerateBodiesAtPoint%3ausingBlock%3a) to make sure you only allow jumping when the physics bodies associated node is a Block.

**Update:**

These methods are available on the SKPhysicsWorld class you can access the instance via the physicsWorld property on your scene.

```
//Please note that this point is in the scenes coordinate system
CGPoint thePointDirectlyBelowMyNode = ...;
[scene.physicWorld bodyAtPoint:thePointDirectlyBelowMyNode];
```

Comment: [bodyInRect:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsWorld/bodyInRect:) or [bodyAlongRayStart:end:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsWorld/bodyAlongRayStart:end:) may also be good candidates if you need greater control.

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't have the time to do the work for you.  You might be lucky and someone else might answer.

Comment: Is there a particular part of using this approach you don't understand?  Maybe I can still point you in the right direction.

Comment: If I am using bodyAtPoint: it says there is no visible @interface for SKSpriteNode declares the selector bodyAtPoint.

Answer (score 0):

In my game, I am using `intersectsNode` to determine if two nodes are intersecting:

`if ( [node1 intersectsNode:node2] )`

Hope this helps

Comment: I used this now, and now the Human doesn't jump at all, so its the same problem as before.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the method is `- (SKNode *)nodeAtPoint:(CGPoint)p;` 
So use `[self nodeAtPoint: pointBelowHuman];`

Comment: Whilst this method might work in some scenarios it is probably better to actually use the physics bodies.  A nodes bounds may extend beyond its collidable physics body, meaning you might still be able to jump, when not on a solid surface.